# Web Server has no internet access, can I somehow use the Client's internet access to make api calls?

Tags: asp.net, json, api, webforms

Argh.  The server I've been given to develop our new intranet has no internet access.  Problem is that ALL our data is json from an API on another website.

The clients DO have internet access and so I've been trying to use JavaScript to do this but I'm really, really not a JS guy and I'm finding this really complicated with promises and callbacks.

Is there some kind of service that I can use from the backend that would connect to the API as the client, instead of the server but still return the data Server side so I can work in C#?

Comment: You _can_ do this in a roundabout way. The server would need to tell the client exactly what kind of API call it needs, the client would make the `ajax` call to the api, and pass the response back to the server to be deserialized and handled in C#. You need to learn how to use AJAX to accomplish this.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. If ALL your data comes from internet... ask for internet access on the server, what if no clients are connected to the server?

Comment: @Jacopo I agree... I assume that this server has _something_ on it that the clients need other than the API, otherwise there would be no need for a server.

Comment: I work for the military..this Server will NEVER have internet access.  The information we are providing comes from a private company who has provided an API to us.

Comment: The server must be isolated from the internet, but clients connected to it's intranet does not, this sounds even more strange to me.
Btw, asnwering the question, i think the best way to redirect internet traffic from a client to a server, through a browser, is indeed javascript. But that requires some more js knowledge than an hello world script, nothing impossible though

Comment: if possible, I'd rather just do as the first comment suggest, make an ajax call and send the code to an asmx...assuming that works..i'm just looking for some example code.

Comment: If you work for the military, please take the time to learn how to do this properly, or tell your superiors that the project scope is over your head... this doesn't sound like a job that should be done poorly.

Comment: I gave up trying to do it this way and am simply doing it all Client Side

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to do it this way and am simply doing it all Client Side